# How to prove that $(\ln t) ^{ -t}$ approaches zero at infinity?

Tags: limits

It seems intuitively that

$\lim_{t\to\infty} (\ln{t})^{-t} = 0$

But how to prove it strictly?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Yep, it's allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well $\lim_{t\to\infty}2^{-t}=0$, and $0<(\ln t)^{-t}<2^{-t}$ for $t>\mathrm e^2$, which implies what you want.

[edit: for a formal proof of the first bit, for any $\delta>0$, if $t>\log_2(1/\delta)$ then $|2^{-t}|<\delta$.]

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
0<(\ln t)^{-t}=\frac{1}{(\ln t)^t}<\frac{1}{\ln t}
$$
for $t>e$.